# Java Change Another Applications' Sound

Tags: java, system, volume, javasound

I am now interested in changing volume of my system. I am running on Windows 8 and I found several of codes that can change "java application's" volume only. But I want to change not only my applications volume but also system's volume.

I used this but did not worked:

```
Mixer.Info[] infos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        for (Mixer.Info info : infos) {
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
            if (mixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.HEADPHONE)) {
                Port port;
                try {
                    port = (Port) mixer.getLine(Port.Info.HEADPHONE);
                    port.open();
                    if (port.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME)) {
                        FloatControl bc = (FloatControl) port
                                .getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
                        System.out.println(info);
                        System.out.println("  - " + bc.getValue());
                        bc.setValue(0.1f);
                    }
                    port.close();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Thi code only changes javaw.exe's volume. For example if anyone plays youtube video on google chrome, it is impossible to change chrome's volume.

Which is the best way to control all system's volume ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Do you have any idea ?"*  Use a language that lets you get close to the OS & hardware (I.E.  **not** Java).

Comment: I could not understand what you mean with that. My english is not so good so if you can help I can write better questions. Sorry...

Comment: Java would not be the computer language I would use for this, because it cannot achieve it.  To achieve 'muting the volume' will require something like C++.